# Highlight local variables, object attributes and constants in Emacs24 + CEDET

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, cedet

I'm relatively new to Emacs and I have recently set it up as an IDE to develop C++ (emacs24 + builtin CEDET + ECB from cvs). I am enjoying the results so far but I'd like some custom highlighting which doesn't seem to exist by default.

When I declare a new constant, local variable or object attribute they appear in a different color. However, when they are used somewhere else, they are displayed as normal text. I'd like to make the constants to be displayed in another color + italics (for example) when they are used somewhere in the code after being declared.

Is there any way to achieve that? I have tried to `C-u C-x =` to see the enabled faces and customize them, but it doesn't seem to notice that I'm over a special symbol and not ordinary text. ECB displays them as variables or attributes in one of its windows.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable, the coloring is done with font-lock, and is related to the syntax of the declaration.  Uses of a variable or function are indistinct and can't really be identified.

If you are referring to the Senator menu item that lets you color a tag in some way, that only colors that tag.  It doesn't know how to track the occurances down.  To track occurances, you need to use `semantic-symref` or similar tool, probably with a more advanced back-end like GNU Global.

There is a useful mode you can enable with `semantic-idle-local-symbol-highlight` that will do special highlighting for the symbol you are on, but it doesn't really match what you are looking for.

Comment: So it's not easy to use a different face for all the symbols that are considered local variables, object members, etc. I just thought that highlighting all the object members (like Eclipse does, for example) would be a nice feature to have, but I can live without it. I am already using `semantic-idle-local-symbol-highlight`; thanks for your answer :)